Teams application hosted media bot not calling webhook
I have setup a media bot as per the instructions mentioned in PsiBot. The TCP address has been added in the firewall. Necessary API permissions in App Registration has been provided. Currently, testing on local computer using ngrok and followed the instructions mentioned in the link above.
Issues:

In an online teams meeting an App is added to the meeting and a call to JoinCallAsync api for bot to join the call occurs, which is successful. But after that nothing happens. The bot is not added in the meeting.
The call to webhook (api/calling) should be called which is not happening. Teams Endpoint webhook

Please guide what should be done to add the bot to the meeting to fetch the audio of participants.

Ngrok points TCP to:
Forwarding tcp://0.tcp.in.ngrok.io:12345 -> localhost:8445

In domain added the below record:
CNAME 0.local.bot mapped to 0.tcp.in.ngrok.io

Created certificate using openssl for *.local.bot.example.com and added in the Microsoft Management Control under Personal Certificates. The program has accepted this certificate i.e. no exception occurred.

Added all the ports, domains, endpoints, application id in the appsettings of the project.

Set supportsCalling to true in manifest file


How can the issue be traced? Please guide.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The link to the code has been provided in the first line.

I've resolved these issues. This can be closed.
